# SQL Server Connection String: Can the password be encrypted in line?

Tags: sql-server

I have an app, a commercial app, that stores its connection string in clear in the registry.

When I used a trusted connection to SQL Server, this is fine (the user id and password are in the IIS app, and are stored encrypted within IIS).

I now must move to SQL auth, and away from a trusted connection (long story).

I dream of a conn string like this:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=@#$@#@%#$%#$<encrypted password>@#$@#$;encryptedpassword=yes;
```

And a way that I can encrypt the pw (using the machine key or such).

Is there a path in this direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: NO

There is no way to do inline encryption in a way that the machine or app will automatically encrypt or decrypt.

The solutions are:

1. Use .NET .config encryption (for example as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx))
2. Roll your own encryption
3. Use a trusted connection

There appear to be no other solutions to this.

Answer (score 3):

This is more for SO than DBA, but if you are using the identity/password for the app pool in IIS it will encrypt the password for you when it is stored. However, be aware that even with this process [passwords can still be decrypted with not much work](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/iis-encrypting-apppool-identity-passwords/).

The connection string itself does not allow you to enter an encrypted password, the mechanism that is saving the connection string handles encrypting sensitive data (or should).